# XAML/Win8.1 app - how to scale with window resize/different resoutions

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

I have a Windows 8.1 app that will be used on a few different resolutions. I had built the app out in 1920x1080, but the client expects now that if they put it on a laptop with 1440x900 or whatnot, it'll scale down to a certain extent.

My question is, is there some way I can wrap my screens in that will literally scale the application interface as the user scales their screen?

The app is fairly simple. It's a MainPage.Xaml, with several child user controls.

```
<Grid Background="white">
    <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="894" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1820" Source="Assets/1920x1080_video_loop.mp4" IsLooping="True" IsMuted="True" Margin="52,156,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" Tapped="Body_Tapped"/>
    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,152,0,0" Stroke="#a7a9ab" VerticalAlignment="Top" StrokeThickness="4" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Height="900" Width="1824"/>
    <Image x:Name="image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="53,77,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="233" Source="Assets/Raytheon_logo.png"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtTitleBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="335,72,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="BORDER SECURITY &amp; CRITICAL INFRASTRUCTURE PROTECTION" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="43" Width="1422" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-Condensed.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 57 Condensed" FontSize="45.333" Foreground="#FF807E82" CharacterSpacing="-25" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemRA" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1470,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="RAYTHEON ADVANTAGE" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-LightCn.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 47 Light Condensed" FontSize="17.333" CharacterSpacing="-35" Tapped="menuItemRA_Tapped" Foreground="#FF807E82"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemRALine" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1623,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="|" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-LightCn.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 47 Light Condensed" FontSize="17.333" CharacterSpacing="-35" Foreground="#FF807E82"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemTS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1633,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TAILORED SOLUTIONS" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-LightCn.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 47 Light Condensed" FontSize="17.333" CharacterSpacing="-35" Tapped="menuItemTS_Tapped" Foreground="#FF807E82"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Line" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1769,24,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="|" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-LightCn.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 47 Light Condensed" FontSize="17.333" CharacterSpacing="-35" Foreground="#FF807E82"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="menuItemCU" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1777,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="CONTACT US" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/FrutigerLTCom-LightCn.ttf#Frutiger LT Com, 47 Light Condensed" FontSize="17.333" CharacterSpacing="-35" RenderTransformOrigin="0.471,0.545" Width="101" Foreground="#FF807E82" Tapped="menuItemCU_Tapped"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1470,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1633,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="131" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar03" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="5" Margin="1778,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_01" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1633,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_02" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1646,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_03" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1659,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_04" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1672,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_05" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1685,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_06" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1698,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_07" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1711,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_08" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1724,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_09" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1737,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Rectangle Name="MenuBar02_10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="7" Margin="1750,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="13.1" Fill="#FFE21836" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

    <local:Page01 Margin="54,156,48,10" x:Name="Page01" Tapped="Body_Tapped" />
    <local:Page29 Margin="54,156,48,10" x:Name="Page29" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0"/>
    <local:Page03 Margin="32,156,29,10" x:Name="Page03" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0"/>
    <local:Page11 Margin="54,156,48,10" x:Name="Page11" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0"/>
    <local:Page02 Margin="53,156,48,0" x:Name="Page02" Visibility="Collapsed" Opacity="0" />

    <Image x:Name="imgFooter1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="908,981,0,-1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Source="Assets/1920x1080_StartHere.png" Tapped="Body_Tapped"/>
    <Image x:Name="imgFooter2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="680,894,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="582" Source="Assets/1920x1080_Tagline.png" Tapped="Body_Tapped"/>
</Grid>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you could do is presume a minimum and a maximum resolution that you will support. Then accordingly set the margins/ alignments and etc.I also see that you have used Margins to get your alignments which is not wise. Use Rows, columns and horizontal and vertical alignments and panels appropriately

Comment: So if I define those grid rows/colums and remove those from the controls themselves, the app will scale?

Comment: They wouldn't scale, but the UI would support a range of resolutions.

Comment: what is needed to actually allow the app to scale? or does it just detect the resolution and start scaled?